# the property id is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I trying  to update a data with EF I got error its like

> the property id is part of the object's key information and cannot be
>   modified

Thıs ıs wınForm Application
you can see my update method here

## region Update

```
        try
        {
            _truck.plateNumber= txtplateNumber.Text;
            _truck.brand = txtMarka.Text;
            _truck.model = txtModel.Text;
            _truck.type = txtTipi.Text;
            _truck.registrationDate = dtregistrationDate.Value;
            _truck.examinationDate = dtexaminationDate.Value;
            _truck.Description = txtDescription.Text;
            _truck.driverName = txtdriverName.Text;
            _truck.weight= txtweight.Text;
            _truck.Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtplateNumber.Tag);
            _truck.userId = Tools.Tools.getUserId();

            #region update
            currentItem = cr.getbyId(Convert.ToInt32(txtplateNumber.Tag.ToString())).plateNumber;

            if (currentItem != null)
            {
                if (!currentItem.Equals(txtplateNumber.Text))
                {
                    if (!cr.isPlateAlreadyExist(txtplateNumber.Text))
                    {
                       DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to update to Truck?", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.pbLicence.ImageLocation))
                            {
                                _truck.licencePicture = Tools.Tools.convertToByteFfromImageF(pbLicence.Image);

                                if (!cr.getbyId(Convert.ToInt32(txtplateNumber.Tag)).hasPicture)
                                {
                                    _truck.hasPicture = true;
                                    cr.Update(_truck);
                                }
                            }

                            cr.Update(_truck);
                            MessageBox.Show("Successfuly");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("The process was Cancel !", "Canceled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The plate number is already Exists.", "Same Plate Number", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to update to Truck?", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.pbLicence.ImageLocation))
                        {
                            _truck.licencePicture = Tools.Tools.convertToByteFfromImageF(this.pbLicence.Image);

                            if (!cr.getbyId(Convert.ToInt32(txtplateNumber.Tag)).hasPicture)
                            {
                                _truck.hasPicture = true;
                                cr.Update(_truck);
                            }
                        }

                        cr.Update(_truck);
                        MessageBox.Show("SuccessFully");
                    }

                }
            #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You did not select an Item","Warning");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
            getUpdatedList();
            Tools.Tools.clearAllFormControlsContent(pickTruckControls());
        }
        #endregion
```

------Repository Update method---------

```
public int Update(Truck item)
    {
        Truck updated = db.Trucks.Where(x => x.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.Entry(updated).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
        return db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are getting is accurate--you are setting the _truck.Id property, which by convention, is a primary key/identity field used by Entity Framework.  You may want to simply add another field to your database, and to your data model if you are using EF Code First, to hold the txtplateNumber.Tag value.  Either way, you are going to need to remove the code setting that value to _truck.Id.

Comment: I did it before and I tried again your answer but its throw same error

Comment: @Emre Not sure if you updated your code above, but it still looks like you are trying to set the value near the top, where you're setting initial values of your _truck model:  
    _truck.Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtplateNumber.Tag); 
This will throw the exception you are talking about...

Comment: its ok I changed my code But this time when I add 2 different item and when I try to select first item and change it some values and Update it.First and second item happing same. And firs item Id coming null...